# Can i run batch file as admin on iis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sphinx, iis-8

I have an ASP.NET MVC application.  Sometimes it must run a .bat file in the root directory, but this works only if it is run as admin. I don't want to change permissions for the whole application.  Can permissions be set only for the .bat file? (The .bat file updates an index in sphinx)

Comment: You could create a windows service to run it for you, instead running it from a website. Windows services allows you to run stuff under system privileges.

Comment: This is the only way?

Comment: Create a Scheduled Task for this - programming a Windows Service would be total overkill.

Comment: Have you considered maybe running Sphinx as the same user as IIS. That way the indexer and searchd could be running as same user. Not entirely sure how to run a Service (ie searchd) as a specific user.

Comment: @Sergei not at all. As you can see, if it is THAT simple, you could just create a schedule task, as Filburt said.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is you create an administrative user on the server then when you run the `System.Process.Start(` to launch the batch file you [pass in the administrator's credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat(v=vs.110).aspx). This should launch the process in the elevated state under the administrative user's credentials.

Comment: I tried run process with administrative credentials, but it did not help. Although if i click on bat file run as administrator it's work and if i run VS it's ok. Maybe i do something wrong?